# Create custom whitespace tag based on number of spaces for NLP pre-processing

Tags: python, regex, replace

To avoid being incorrectly flagged as a duplicate (though if I *have* missed something in my Google searches, I will be happily proven wrong), I have done some research on my own and found this so far in regards to handling whitespace:

A lot of what I could find on the web seems to be geared towards (1) finding whitespace and replacing it with something static, (2) methods of quantifying whitespace in a given string in totality, not in chunks.

What has been difficult to find is how to slide along a string, stop when a section of whitespace has been reached, and replace that section of the string with a variable which depends on how large that whitespace is.

**My question:**

I am doing some NLP work and my data often has discrete amount of whitespace between values (and sometimes at the very beginning of the line)

e.g.:

> `field_header          field_value    field_code\n`
>
> `.      Sometimes   there are gaps      at the beginning too.`

The data also contains some standard text with single spaces in between:

> `There are standard sentences which are embedded in the documents as well.\n`

I want to replace all whitespace that is larger than a single space so my document now looks something like this:

> `field_head WS_10 field_value WS_4 field_code\n`
>
> `. WS_6 Sometimes WS_3 there are gaps WS_6 at the beginning too.`
>
> `There are standard sentences which are embedded in the documents as well.\n`

Where *WS_n* is a token which represents the amount (n >= 2) of whitespace between each word and is padded by a space on either side.

I tried to find the whitespace using regex and separately count the number of whitespaces using `.count()`- but that obviously doesn't work. I know how to use `re.sub`, but it doesn't allow for specific substitutions which depend on what is picked up by the regex.

```
s = 'Some part      of my     text file   with irregular     spacing.\n'
pattern = '\ {2,}'

subsitution = ' WS_'+str(???.count(' '))+' '

re.sub(pattern, substitution, s)
```

If the above example did what it was supposed to, I'd get back:

`'Some part WS_6 of my WS_5 text file WS_3 with irregular WS_6 spacing.\n'`

Comment: @Trenton_M I am not simply trying to remove multiple spaces - I am trying to replace the multiple spaces based upon how many spaces there were, which I don't think that linked question answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Without regular expressions:

```
s1 = 'Some part      of my     text file   with irregular     spacing.\n'
s2 = '          Some part      of my     text file   with irregular     spacing.\n'

def fix_sentence(sentence: str) -> str:
    ws_1st_char = True  # used to properly count whitespace at the beginning of the sentence
    count, new_sentence = 0, ''
    for x in sentence.split(' '):
        if x != '':
            if count != 0:
                if ws_1st_char: z = count
                else: z = count + 1
                new_sentence = new_sentence + f'WS_{z} '
            new_sentence = new_sentence + f'{x} '
            count = 0
            ws_1st_char = False
        else:
            count+=1
    return new_sentence.rstrip(' ')

fixed1 = fix_sentence(s1)
fixed2 = fix_sentence(s2)

print(fixed1)
>>> 'Some part WS_6 of my WS_5 text file WS_3 with irregular WS_5 spacing.\n'

print(fixed2)
>>> 'WS_10 Some part WS_6 of my WS_5 text file WS_3 with irregular WS_5 spacing.\n'
```

### If there is never white space at the beginning of the sentence:

```
def fix_sentence(sentence: str) -> str:
    count, new_sentence = 0, ''
    for x in sentence.split(' '):
        if x != '':
            if count != 0:
                new_sentence = new_sentence + f'WS_{count + 1} '
            new_sentence = new_sentence + f'{x} '
            count = 0
        else:
            count+=1
    return new_sentence.rstrip(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def replace_whitespace(string):
    while True:
        whitespace = re.search("\s{2,}", string)
        if whitespace:
            whitespace = whitespace.group()
            string = re.sub(f"(?<=\S){whitespace}(?=\S)", f" WS_{len(whitespace)} ", string)
        else:
            break
    return string


string = "Some part      of my     text file   with irregular     spacing.\n"
print(replace_whitespace(string))
```

This function finds the whitespace and replaces it with the given string. `re.sub` cannot use regex for the `repl` (replace) parameter so the value is calculated in the loop as it is found. Even if it could regex cannot count the length of a string.

Output:
`Some part WS_6 of my WS_5 text file WS_3 with irregular WS_5 spacing.\n`

Comment: This breaks if there is more than 1 whitespace at the beginning of the sentence. I don't know if that is a possible condition for the question.

Comment: There is indeed occasionally 1+ whitespace at the beginning of a line; will add to main body of my question to clarify.